# Sony Smartwatch SW2 - accelerometer output rate

Tags: accelerometer, sony, sony-smartwatch

From the sample code of the SDK, I can read the accelerometer at 4-5Hz by using:

`registerListener(listener, Sensor.SensorRates.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST,
                Sensor.SensorInterruptMode.SENSOR_INTERRUPT_ENABLED);`

but it does not work when using registerFixedRateListener().
How to read accelerometer data from SW2 with higher rate? for example 10Hz, 20Hz...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to read values on my SW 2 at 10Hz with disabled interrupts using

```
sensor.registerFixedRateListener(mListener, Sensor.SensorRates.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

However, 10 Hz seems to be the limit.

Comment: Thanks Amark. It seems that the output rate on SW2 is very limited.